# Ubuntu with Windows 10 on VMware or vice versa

Tags: windows-10, vmware

Is it recommended to install Windows on VMware for basic use like office and Skype? How seamless is it to use VMware Windows on regular basis?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not a good option. Windows is quite resource intensive, you need reserve at least 8Gb RAM for VM.

Additionally it's just uncomfortable to use a virtual machine for user applications.

You can use Libre office and skype in Linux. They work stable enough.

Comment: Basically, it would be preferable to install Windows OS and use Ubuntu on VMware. Is that correct?